# Cocoapod : warning: URI.escape is obsolete

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

/Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 10):

Looks like the upcoming CocoaPods 1.10.0 will remove the deprecation warnings. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9491. In the mean time, I wouldn't worry about it. These are just warnings and shouldn't currently cause any issues.

If you *really* want to remove the warnings you can disable all Ruby warnings using the `RUBYOPT` environment variable like this:

`export RUBYOPT='-W0'`

Although I wouldn't recommend it as you risk missing something important in the future.

Comment: `alias pod='RUBYOPT=-W0 pod'` temporarily might help ;)

Answer (score 2):

upgrading ruby to 2.7.2 and reinstall cocoapods 1.10.0 can fix

```
brew upgrade ruby
gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score -1):

Same problems with ruby 2.7.1 and 2.7.2 but SOLVED for me with installing ruby 2.6.6:
if you don't have homebrew installed:

1. install homebrew: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. install rbenv (version manager): `brew install rbenv ruby-build`
3. prepare a terminal: `echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile source ~/.bash_profile`
4. install Ruby: `rbenv install 2.6.6`
5. activate the version: `rbenv global 2.6.6`
6. verify the activated version: `ruby -v`

then reinstall cocoapods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
and in the app folder run:`pod install`

Answer (score -3):

Try the following:

```
  sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Won't fix here.  ruby -v 
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]

Answer (score -3):

First, remove old cocoapods:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then, install it again and override:

```
brew install cocoapods --build-from-source
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

It worked for me after upgrating to Catalina